# pd.ExcelWriter: export file defined in a variable to folder already created

Tags: spreadsheet-excel-writer

1. I create the output folder inside the directory where the script is located

```py
dirName = './output'

os.makedirs(dirName, exist_ok=True)
```

2. I defined the name of the xlsx file that included the date:

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

datestr = now.strftime("%d%b%Y")

x = 'output_{}.xlsx'.format(datestr)
```

3. This is the tricky part, since I cannot place x inside './output'

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(x, engine='xlsxwriter')
```

How can I create a path that includes the folder `'./output'` where the x object should be placed?